# How to solve the issues when updating version of my App in iOS App Store?

Tags: iphone

I released the version 1.1,1.2 to App store and now i am trying to release the version 1.3,i am getting the following issues when archiving the project in xcode.

[image]

This is my info.plist

[image]

Please help me how to solve the above problem.

Comment: This is an urgent need of mine..I am really looking forward your kind response..

Comment: I suggest you to remove all your image and then name them according to [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html)

Comment: Yes i got the solutions..I was successfully updated version to AppStore..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's looking in the wrong place for your app icons and you are also using private API's. Those are the bottom two errors respectively.

Go to your target settings > general > app icons > source and select Don't use assets catalogs?

Comment: Can u explain little bit briefly :(

Comment: Its looking for your icons in the software assets directory. 

Also in JilJIl Radio: startIndex 

You are referencing a non-public selector... Check your code for a warning about it ... Although this is only a warning it will still submit to Apple but they are likely to reject on that basis.

Comment: No i am not looking for an warning solution...I want the solution for Invalid image path:No image found at the path referenced under key:CFBundleIconFiles

Comment: OK, Go to your target settings > general > app icons > source and select Don't use assets catalogs?

Comment: In your plist, whats in the icon files array ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45788/discussion-between-user1087669-and-cw0007007)